# Assigning color to nodes in a graph such that no two neighbor nodes to it has same color

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx, graph-theory, greedy

[image]

If you see the above graph, no nodes next to each other has the same color. I created a grid graph with diagonal edges across nodes using networkx python and applied greedy color to it.

```
greed = nx.coloring.greedy_color(G)
print(greed)
```

which gives the output

```
{(1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 1, (1, 5): 0, (1, 6): 1, (1, 7): 0, (1, 8): 1, (2, 1): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 2, (2, 6): 3, (2, 7): 2, (2, 8): 3, (3, 1): 0, (3, 2): 1, (3, 3): 0, (3, 4): 1, (3, 5): 0, (3, 6): 1, (3, 7): 0, (3, 8): 1, (4, 1): 2, (4, 2): 3, (4, 3): 2, (4, 4): 3, (4, 5): 2, (4, 6): 3, (4, 7): 2, (4, 8): 3, (5, 1): 0, (5, 2): 1, (5, 3): 0, (5, 4): 1, (5, 5): 0, (5, 6): 1, (5, 7): 0, (5, 8): 1, (6, 1): 2, (6, 2): 3, (6, 3): 2, (6, 4): 3, (6, 5): 2, (6, 6): 3, (6, 7): 2, (6, 8): 3, (7, 1): 0, (7, 2): 1, (7, 3): 0, (7, 4): 1, (7, 5): 0, (7, 6): 1, (7, 7): 0, (7, 8): 1, (8, 1): 2, (8, 2): 3, (8, 3): 2, (8, 4): 3, (8, 5): 2, (8, 6): 3, (8, 7): 2, (8, 8): 3, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 3, (0, 5): 2, (0, 6): 3, (0, 7): 2, (0, 8): 3, (1, 0): 1, (1, 9): 0, (2, 0): 3, (2, 9): 2, (3, 0): 1, (3, 9): 0, (4, 0): 3, (4, 9): 2, (5, 0): 1, (5, 9): 0, (6, 0): 3, (6, 9): 2, (7, 0): 1, (7, 9): 0, (8, 0): 3, (8, 9): 2, (9, 1): 0, (9, 2): 1, (9, 3): 0, (9, 4): 1, (9, 5): 0, (9, 6): 1, (9, 7): 0, (9, 8): 1, (0, 0): 3, (0, 9): 2, (9, 0): 1, (9, 9): 0}
```

after sorting

```
{(0, 0): 3, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 3, (0, 5): 2, (0, 6): 3, (0, 7): 2, (0, 8): 3, (0, 9): 2, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 1, (1, 5): 0, (1, 6): 1, (1, 7): 0, (1, 8): 1, (1, 9): 0, (2, 0): 3, (2, 1): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 2, (2, 6): 3, (2, 7): 2, (2, 8): 3, (2, 9): 2, (3, 0): 1, (3, 1): 0, (3, 2): 1, (3, 3): 0, (3, 4): 1, (3, 5): 0, (3, 6): 1, (3, 7): 0, (3, 8): 1, (3, 9): 0, (4, 0): 3, (4, 1): 2, (4, 2): 3, (4, 3): 2, (4, 4): 3, (4, 5): 2, (4, 6): 3, (4, 7): 2, (4, 8): 3, (4, 9): 2, (5, 0): 1, (5, 1): 0, (5, 2): 1, (5, 3): 0, (5, 4): 1, (5, 5): 0, (5, 6): 1, (5, 7): 0, (5, 8): 1, (5, 9): 0, (6, 0): 3, (6, 1): 2, (6, 2): 3, (6, 3): 2, (6, 4): 3, (6, 5): 2, (6, 6): 3, (6, 7): 2, (6, 8): 3, (6, 9): 2, (7, 0): 1, (7, 1): 0, (7, 2): 1, (7, 3): 0, (7, 4): 1, (7, 5): 0, (7, 6): 1, (7, 7): 0, (7, 8): 1, (7, 9): 0, (8, 0): 3, (8, 1): 2, (8, 2): 3, (8, 3): 2, (8, 4): 3, (8, 5): 2, (8, 6): 3, (8, 7): 2, (8, 8): 3, (8, 9): 2, (9, 0): 1, (9, 1): 0, (9, 2): 1, (9, 3): 0, (9, 4): 1, (9, 5): 0, (9, 6): 1, (9, 7): 0, (9, 8): 1, (9, 9): 0}
```

But I want it to be in such a way that no two adjacent/neighbor nodes to a node should have the same color [image]

In the above figure, (1,4) [green] has its neighbors (1,3) [red] and (1,5) [red]. In this case both nodes next to node (1,4) are red. But I want (1,3) and (1,5) in different colors. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

I tried greedy color method from networkx to color in such a way that no two nodes adjacent to each other have the same color.

Comment: create a copy of the graph, add edges to nodes if they share a common neighbour, color the graph, report colors to original graph

Comment: Can you please be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: what don't you understand ? It's far easier if you tell me what isn't than for me to rewrite everything

Comment: You want me to replace nodes with edges and color them? Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: No, that's no it. You don't replace node with edges, you add additional edges to force the constraint you have on the coloring algorithm. I added a complete answer below, feel free to comment there if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have an additional constraint that the coloring algorithm does not respect. You have two choice : change the algorithm to respect the constraint (hard), change the data (the graph) so that the constraints are integrated in it.

The second option is really easy to do here. All we have to do is add edges between nodes that should not be the same color (that is, nodes that share a common neighbor), color the graph.

1. Create a deep copy `G2` of the graph `G`. As we will modify the graph to match the new constraints, we have to keep the original intact.
2. For every pair of nodes `n_1`, `n_2` in `G` :

   1. If they are adjacent, nothing to do.
   2. If they share a common neighbor in `G`, add an edge `(n_1, n_2)` in `G2`
3. Color `G2`
4. For every node in `G`, set it's color to the color of the corresponding node in `G2`

Comment: The nodes with common neighbor will have an edge running over it in G2 right?

Comment: If you represent it with straight edges, yes it will. But `G2` is just a trick, and a graph is just data, don't think about it graphically but as relations.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the Graph Coloring algorithm?

Step 1 − Arrange the vertices of the graph in some order.

Step 2 − Choose the first vertex and color it with the first color.

Step 3 − Choose the next vertex and color it with the lowest numbered color that has not been colored on any vertices adjacent to it. If all the adjacent vertices are colored with this color, assign a new color to it. Repeat this step until all the vertices are colored.

credits : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/the-graph-coloring

Comment: coloring the graph is not the problem, the problem is that there's additional constraint about coloring.